# Bootstrap 5 tooltip design

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tooltip, bootstrap-5

Please advise me how could I push specific tag attributes (like class, style, etc.) from tooltip title. To demonstrate the issue here's my [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/w549zn1d/1/). Hovering works as hovering onto the table cell text: Apple, and I'm trying to get the tooltip table header in green for example.
I assume the solution might be hiding in the proper setting of whiteList-allowList and extend to all html attributes, but I'm unable to find a solution... Any help appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});

var myDefaultAllowList = bootstrap.Tooltip.Default.allowList;
myDefaultAllowList.table = [];
myDefaultAllowList.tr = [];
myDefaultAllowList.td = [];
myDefaultAllowList.th = [];
myDefaultAllowList.tbody = [];
myDefaultAllowList.thead = [];
```

Comment: HI, you mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/axt2k5sf/) ?

Comment: Tnx Swati! Solved.